# How does pagination work in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I created pagination by writing

```
$users = User::paginate(25);
```

Then to display the links, I used the following command,

```
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

As the command given below no longer works in Laravel 5

```
{{$users->links()}}
```

`{!! $users->render() !!}`  displays the pagination links in the view but there is a slight issue with the links.

This link it generates is like this

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/users/?page=2
```

How can I change the generated link to something like this

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/users?page=2
```

i.e to remove the slash(/) after users in the url?

The reason for this is that the url with slash after users fails.

Any help regarding pagination will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following `$users->setPath('')->render();`. I had a similar situation and this fixed the issue for me.